# Magento 2 error in swatchRenderer.js with configurable product image

Tags: magento-2.1.7, third-party-module, configurable-swatches

I am getting error when click on the configurable product `swatch` and image is not changing.

> TypeError: gallery is undefined

It is working with default zoom functionality but I'm using [an extension](https://magentodeveloper.in/product-zoom-pro-extension-for-magento2.html).

Functionality is not working with this image changing. Any one can say what is issue with this?

https://ktree.com/uploads/ktree_zoom-0.0.1.zip

Answer (score 0):

open below file:

```
vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
```

add below code at line no : 714. before  `if (result.oldPrice.amount !== result.finalPrice.amount) {`

```
if (typeof(result) == 'undefined') {        
                result = $widget.options.jsonConfig.prices;     
            }
```

Please flush your cache after change this file.

Comment: Not working still i m getting same error TypeError: gallery is undefined

Comment: did you check this code is applied successfully in you js ? check this js url using pub/ path.

Comment: Yes i have checked this code was applied.